# What's the little red arrow / green rectangle / blue rectangle in VS Code in the narrow space between the line numbers and the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

See here, between line 15 and 16. Does it just indicate a blank line? If so, why?

[image: Red arrow in Visual Studio Code.]

Answer (score 177, accepted):

It called a "Gutter Indicator".

It means a line has been deleted from the previous version of the file (based on git).

Comment: Or perhaps added? Doesn't seem to show up when I delete a line. But it does when I add one, and then only sometimes!

Comment: Then probably a bug :-) I've seen a few of them already, buy it's documents to mean a deleted line (look it up)

Comment: This can be controlled by "scm.diffDecorations" under the settings file. For example - "none" will make this arrow go away for ever and ever (or at least until you put is back on, with "gutter", for example) :-) Happy coding!

Comment: I wanted to make it other than red, but not dissappear. For others seeking this answer it is: `settings.json -> "workbench.colorCustomizations" -> "editorGutter.deletedBackground"`

Answer (score 1):

If you hoover / click on that red arrow, you get to see the prior version of your code (displaying what you deleted)

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In [the VS Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), these are called "SCM diff decorations" (The relevant setting's ID is `scm.diffDecorations`). SCM is short for ["source control management"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Note that in VS Code 1.86, there will be tooltips describing what they are when you hover your mouse over them. See [Provide tooltip for gutter actions #152088](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152088).

Generally speaking (barring a colour theme that changes this convention), red means a line(s) of code has been removed, green means a line(s) of code has been added, and blue means a line(s) of code has been modified.

When you click on the diff decoration, by default (barring changes to settings like `scm.diffDecorationsGutterAction`), it will open an inline panel showing what exactly has changed. This feature is called ["Quick Diff"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#quick-diff).

Some people call them "Git diff decorations", but that's not quite right since Git is just one type of SCM software (there are others like Subversion and Mercurial), and while it happens to have [Git support as a builtin extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/git) because Git is so dominant, it supports the feature for any SCM software. From [the extension development docs on the Quick Diff feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#quick-diff):

> These decorations are computed by VS Code itself. All you need to do is provide VS Code with the original contents of any given file.

---

In the implementation in the DOM (VS Code is Electron (Chromium)-based), they are given classnames like `dirty-diff-glyph`, `dirty-diff-deleted`, `dirty-diff-added`, `dirty-diff-modified`. You can see for yourself with the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

---

I disagree with [Amit's answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235364/11107541). Most (all?) of the official material from the VS Code team uses the term "diff decorations" in reference to this feature, I haven't personally ever seen any maintainers of VS Code refer to diff decorations as "gutter indicators" in other spaces such as issue tickets, and I don't think it's a good term to use for this feature, since there are other things that can equally well be called "gutter indicators" that are *not* diff decorations- for example, breakpoint icons, which also live in the gutter space. And if I understand correctly, any extension can also contribute its own custom decorations in the gutter space (see in particular the `gutterIconPath` and `gutterIconSize` optional properties of [`DecorationRenderOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions)).